# How to use the ActionListener event when clicking on the box to generate the numbers?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I want to get the number 1 to 4 whenever I click on the box. It should happen to all the boxes as shown in the figure. when I select any number it should be selected in the box when I click X it should deselect.

Can someone help me using Swing? I need to do this puzzle.

[image]

Comment: @andrew Thompson could please help

Comment: I already did. I was one of two people who voted to close. That certainly helps the SO community be free of 'questions' which read like 'gimme da codez', and if you're savvy, it helps you to realise that the quality of your questions needs to be improved by putting in more effort. .. You're welcome. :)

Comment: What have you tried ?  Please post [mre] to show what you did and where what exactly you need help with.